# "if it means that" in "Elizabeth Finch" by Julian Barnes

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-finch, julian-barnes

I'm reading *Elizabeth Finch* by Julian Barnes. In this paragraph I have some difficulties:

> We all pursue what we think is best for us, even if it
> means our extinction. Sometimes, **especially if it means that**. By the
> time we attain it, or don’t, it is usually too late anyway.

What is Elizabeth Finch saying by "**especially if it means that**"?
Does it mean that sometimes we search for some special thing that can lead us to extinction?

Comment: To add to Tsundoku's answer below: there is a parallelism of phrases here. The "especially if it means that" is meant to replace the "even if it means [that]" in the previous sentence. Imagine if the second sentence was "We all pursue what we think is best for us, sometimes, especially if it means our extinction". That's the direct meaning of the phrase you've bolded. I just mention this as it's not clear if you'd exactly realised this; for the further meaning/significance of the sentence, go to Tsundoku's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of this novel "especially if it means that" means "especially if *what we think is best for us* means *our extinction*". "Extinction" may seem a strange choice of words because we are used to encountering in the context of species becoming extinct. But "extinction" can also mean annihilation.

In the immediate context, "annihilation" makes sense. A few lines later, we encounter the following statement:

> But in any case, an angel of the Lord appeared to Etherius, instructing him to meet Ursula in Cologne, where they would meet glorious martyrdom together.

In other words, for Etherius "what we think is best for us" refers to meeting Ursula in Cologne, and dying as a martyr meant his "extinction".